# Python/MariaDB: Converting .csv data to Data-frames and exporting to Database

Tags: python, mysql, dataframe, mariadb

For a project I am working on I am attempting to read sensor data that I've stored as a csv file and send it to a database. After some discussion, we realized that converting the .csv data into a data-frame would be easiest for auditing to the database. I have successfully converted the data into a data-frame (yay!) but am running into issues with exporting the data-frame into the database. Here is my code:

```
#first we must convert the data into a dataframe
import pandas as pd 
fileName = 'testing1.csv'
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/danie/Desktop/testing1.csv')

#Now we must send
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('mysql://root:mysecretpassword6@localhost:mysecrethost/mysecretdatabasename') 
#change to connect your mysql

df.to_sql(name='dataframes',con=engine,if_exists='append',index=False)
```

When I am trying to send the data-frame I get the following error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1054, "Unknown column '10' in 'field 
list'") [SQL: 'INSERT INTO dataframes (`10`, `25`, `25.1`, `25.2`, `25.3`, 
`25.4`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'] [parameters: ((20, 486, 486, 486, 
486, 486), (30, 286, 286, 286, 286, 286), (40, 286, 286, 286, 286, 286), (50, 
289, 289, 289, 289, 289), (60, 262, 262, 262, 262, 262), (70, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), 
(80, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154), (90, 5151, 5151, 5151, 5151, 5151)  ... 
displaying 10 of 13 total bound parameter sets ...  (130, 181, 181, 181, 181, 
181), (140, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151))] (Background on this error at: 
http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

The background on the error does not help me solve the problem. But I have identified a problem. If I print the dataframe (df) on python this is what I get:
 [Sorry couldn't format it properly so I uploaded an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTvdA.jpg)
Now this is a problem, because my test .csv file I am creating the dataframe from   does NOT have the same data. Here is an image: [Where you can clearly see there is no '`10`, `25`, `25.1`, `25.2`, `25.3`, 
`25.4` values.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqL30.jpg)

I will try making a new file and testing that to see if it works, but I have all the proper columns made in my database. I do not understand why the data-frame is reading values from the .csv that aren't there. Or maybe I am not seeing any error with my code.

I truly appreciate any help I can get with this error.

Many thanks.

edit1: I should note that this is not the REAL sensor data. This is a trial file.

edit2: I tried with a new file, with new data. Same error. From what I can see, the data-frame is skipping the first line of the .csv file and not inserting it properly into the data-frame. Here is what I mean:

```
     10    25  25.1  25.2  25.3  25.4
0    20   486   486   486   486   486
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. The df.to_sql line was attempting to make the first line of the csv file the column titles. Easy fix, just edit them in the csv file to reflect the name you want them to in the database. IE, move the data down one row in the .csv file and add the titles of the columns.

See: [Excel fix.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0S9S.jpg) [DB Fix.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stpMS.jpg) [Python Fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgAAD.jpg)